# iOS NSURLSession with Wi-Fi Assist turned on results in crashing app

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession

I'm performing an HTTP request using iOS's NSURLSession. My code looks like this:

```
let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

let url = NSURL(string:"www.example.com")

guard let url = url else {
   return
}

let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url)

var task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request){
     (data, response, error) -> Void in

     //do stuff with the data
}

task.resume()
```

(sorry if my code isn't 100% correct I just typed it real quickly inside my browser, you get the idea)

When Wi-Fi Assist is turned off it works fine, but when Wi-Fi Assist is turned on the app crashes.

I found [this](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/20853) but the discussion never got an answer.

Apart from the fact that I want to fix the problem I am very curious WHY this is happening.

Comment: What dose it say in the console log? Are you getting a nil value resulting in the crash?

Comment: The crash happens before the data task is completed.

Comment: Start by adding your real code in to the question then. The code you have submitted has no error checking in it.

Comment: That's not the problem. Then it would break at that point.

Comment: If you place the device in airplane mode do you get the crash?

Comment: No. It has to do with Wi-Fi assist.

Comment: Did you tried an exception breakpoint? here works fine...

Comment: There is simply not enough information here. What's the crash you are getting? Are any errors logged and how are you capturing them? You've identified an issue without enough details for anyone to reproduce it. If the issue can be caused by the textbook-style example code you included, then you should obviously file a radar.